# How do I set the axis limits with wx.lib.plot in Python?

Tags: python, plot, wxpython

The title really says it all. I currently have some Python code which generates a line graph using wx.lib.plot, and I would like to manually set the axis limits. How can I do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would set axis values while calling [PlotCanvas.Draw](https://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.lib.plot.PlotCanvas-class.html#Draw).

```
self.Draw(gc, xAxis=(0,xlimit), yAxis=(0,ylimit))
```

Where `self` is derived from `plot.PlotCanvas`.